# Como insertar información cuando se crea una tabla en nodejs y sequelieze

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, sequelize.js

Hola amigos estoy en nodejs y lo que quiero hacer es insertar datos cuando se crea una tabla con el model que cree con sequelize.

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('platforms', {
        idPlatform: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
        },
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        description: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
        so: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    });
}
```

como puedo insertar un datos por defecto?

el index donde se usa el sync()

```
server.listen(port, () => {

  db.sync()
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Para lo que te propones deberías usar [`migrations`](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/) por una razón muy sencilla: *te permitirá mantener un registro de los cambios realizados en la base de datos y volver a un estado anterior si fuese necesario*.  Lo que tu quieres hacer se llama [*seed*](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/migrations/#creating-the-first-seed), y si lo haces mediante *migrations*, es muy sencillo llenar datos por defecto. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para insertar los datos por defecto al arrancar el servidor, simplemente utiliza `bulkCreate` después de arrancar tu aplicación y sincronizar tu base de datos. Un ejemplo con tu código podría ser:

```
server.listen(3000, async () => {
    await db.sequelize.sync({force: true});
    await db.platforms.bulkCreate([
        {name: "android", description: "Android", so: "android"},
        {name: "ios", description: "iOS", so: "ios"},
        {name: "windows", description: "Windows", so: "windows"},
        {name: "linux", description: "Linux", so: "linux"},
        {name: "mac", description: "Mac", so: "mac"}
    ]);
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
})
```